# "drag n drop" application to convert images to base64 string (for web development)

Tags: applications, applescript

I'm after an osx program that will convert an image into a base64 string (for web development).

Basically replicates this: http://webcodertools.com/imagetobase64converter/Create

I suspect there is no application, and in that case I'd be interested if I can get the terminal command which will encode, to apply to a certain file on Right-Click

<sub>Followup question: [Can I give Automator apps a window?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/127035/can-i-give-automator-apps-a-window)</sub>

## SOLUTION

I combined the two solutions below, to create an application with the following code

```
for f in "$@"
do
    openssl base64 -in "$f" | pbcopy
done
```

And infact I made a dropzone target using [Platypus](http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus), as shown in [my subsequent SO question/answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/127035/can-i-give-automator-apps-a-window)

Comment: Or use this handy webpage: https://jpillora.com/base64-encoder/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Base64 Automator Droplet

You can use Automator to [create your own Base64 droplet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087148/how-to-make-a-droplet-on-mac-osx-with-automator). Mac OS X includes `openssl` which can encode files to Base64; this superuser question explains how, [OS X: Base64 encode via command line](https://superuser.com/questions/120796/os-x-base64-encode-via-command-line)

1. Launch Automator.app
2. Create a new application
3. Add a **Run Shell Script** action
4. Set **Pass input:** to **as arguments**
5. Within the script, replace `echo` with the script below.
6. Save your workflow as an application

To use your application, drag and drop files onto it. A new base64 encoded file will appear next to the original file.

### Shell Script

```
for f in "$@"
do
    openssl base64 -in "$f" -out "$f.b64"
done
```

[image: Automator Base64 droplet]

To learn more about using Automator, see Apple's [Mac Basics: Automator](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2488).

Answer (score 3):

One of your possibilites is :

- Create an Automator service
- At the top select : Service receives selected **image files** in **Finder**
- Add a Shell Script action
- Put the following script in it

  - `openssl base64 < "$1" | pbcopy`
- Save the service

Now you can from the `contextual menu > Service > yourServiceName` of every image in the finder get the base64 encoding copied into your clipboard !

Comment: Thanks. Hm, first try I couldn't get this to work. I'll have another crack when I get some time. But I did combine the use of pbcopy with another answer!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an Applescript for BBEdit: I only use jpg images for this, but it could be adapted for other images and other editors easily:

```
-- choose file
set _a to choose file of type "jpg"

-- convert path to posix path
set _b to POSIX path of _a

-- strip newlines and place in clipboard
do shell script "openssl enc -base64 -in " & _b & " | tr -d \"\\n\" | pbcopy"
set myClip to the clipboard

-- set strings with placeholder texts for BBEdit
set _start to "<img alt=\"<# some text #>\" width=\"<# width #>\" height=\"<# height #>\" src=\"data:image/jpg;base64,"
set _end to "\" />"
set _string to _start & myClip & _end

tell application "BBEdit"
    set selection to _string
end tell
```