# Can I give Automator apps a window?

Tags: applescript, automator

Can I create a window / UI for applications created using Automator?
Or is this just not possible with Automator apps?

Background:
I created an "application" through Automator, and dragged the app into the Dock and it works fine. However the app does not act like an normal app. e.g. I can't seem to "open" a window for it, or have it in the CMD + Tab menu.

Note: this is a follow up question to: [“drag n drop” application to convert images to base64 string for web development](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/127011/drag-n-drop-application-to-convert-images-to-base64-string-for-web-developmen/127015?noredirect=1#comment148787_127015)

## SOLUTION

As per answer below I used the *free* [platypus](http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus). I simply [created a new script through the UI](http://sveinbjorn.org/files/manpages/PlatypusDocumentation.html#41) and copy and pasted the code I'd used for my Automator app:

```
for f in "$@"
do
    openssl base64 -in "$f" | pbcopy
done
```

Note: this copies the base64 string to clipboard, and thus I assume its only good for simple imgs (which is all I want it for)

Comment: what UI window would that be?

Comment: Anything really, I just want to be able to load up my app via spotlight - and then drag and drop files on it in the CMD + Tab menu. Sure I can have it in my dock, but...I don't really like the dock

Comment: so just a drop box window, that stays open.

Comment: Well, just a window so OSX treats the app like other normal apps. If its in the CMD+Tab menu (which I can drag files onto), or there is a drag / drop target, then I will be happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the application with [Platypus](http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus) instead:

[image]

The application window looks like this:

[image]